# How to use Getx and MVC together in one project

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

If we are using GetX state management and MVC design pattern then how extend our controller for example in Getx we are extending our controller class with GetxController{} and with MVC we extend our class MVCcontroller{} at the same time how use both?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I am fetching API data, I am using the MVC design pattern (mvc_pattern: ^8.10.2) and Getx state management.  when I am extending my controller class with getx state management I use to do " class myController extends GetxController {} "   when I am using MVC then I extend my controller class " class myController extends ControllerMVC "  So i don't understand how I can use both MVC pattern and Getx state management in one project.  

Thank you for your help. I am in the initial learning stage.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use the MVC_pattern package to work with MVC design,
I recommended seeing my project https://github.com/khaledsawan/Products_app-FrontEnd I am using GetX and the design pattern is MVC (this project has auth and crud operation with Api ) .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).